# Expected distance of a point picked at disc

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A point $P$ is picked uniformly over the disc with radius $1$ and center in the origin, after this a new point $Q$ is picked uniformly over the disc with radius $|P|$ and center in the origin.

Im asked to compute $E|Q|$, and given the hint that a random point $(X,Y)$ uniformly distributed over the disc with radius $r>0$ has density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi r^{2}} $, for $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq r$.

Im not sure how to approach this problem, is it $E[Q|P=x ]$ that I should find? If thats the case, then how do I find the conditional distribution?

Answer (score 1):

If we know $P$ then the probability of landing on a point in a region of area $d^2A=Q\,dQ\,d\theta$ is just the areal element over the total accessible area:
$$p(Q,\theta|P)dQ\,d\theta=\frac1{\pi P^2}Q\,dQ\,d\theta$$
In turn, the probability of landing on a point in a region of area $d^2A=P\,dP\,d\phi$ in the unit circle in the first place is the areal element of that region over the area of the unit circle:
$$p(P,\phi)dP\,d\phi=\frac1{\pi}P\,dP\,d\phi$$
So the mean value of $Q$ is
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\frac1{\pi}P\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^P\frac1{\pi P^2}(Q)Q\,dQ\,d\theta\,dP\,d\phi=\frac1{\pi^2}(2\pi)^2\int_0^1\frac1P\frac13P^3\,dP=\frac49$$
**EDIT**: To be more step by step we can go back to the first equation and integrate over angles to get
$$f(Q|P)dQ=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{\pi P^2}Q\,dQ\,d\theta=\frac2{P^2}Q\,dQ$$
Then we can find
$$E[Q|P]=\int_0^PQf(Q|P)dQ=\int_0^PQ\frac2{P^2}Q\,dQ=\left.\frac2{3P^2}Q^3\right|_0^P=\frac{2P}3$$
With this formula in hand we can integrate over $\phi$ to find
$$f(P)=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{\pi}P\,dP\,d\phi=2P\,dP$$
Then we can find
$$E[Q]=\int_0^1E[Q|P]f(P)dP=\int_0^1\frac{2P}32P\,dP=\left.\frac49P^3\right|_0^1=\frac49$$
The notation where the probability density function is never separated from its differential goes back to statistical mechanics where it's always there to remind you of the extra steps (transformation of differential) that need to be undertaken when transforming coordinates in a complex situation.

Comment: Your solution looks nice, but I have a hard time following your notations..


What is the distriution of $Q$ given that $ P=x$? Is it possible to find $f_{Q|P=x}(q)$, and then compute $E[Q|P=x]$ ?

Comment: Tried to make things more comprehensible in the context of a mathematical probability course rather than statistical mechanics.

Comment: Thanks, looks good now. But what do you mean with $f(Q|P)dQ$, what is meant by $dQ$?

Comment: Right, that's the differential that I kept tightly bound to the probability density function. It's really inseparable in that we always need it when we use the probability density. For example we require $$\int_0^Pf(Q|P)dQ=1$$ and evaluate $$E[Q|P]=\int_0^PQf(Q|P)dQ$$ Consider the [Planck blackbody radiation function](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html) (not really a probability but the first thing I could come up with off the top of my head) You will have to go to the link above and scroll down to see distribution with respect to wavelength and frequency.

Comment: Ah okay I see, but how does one conclude that $f(Q|P)=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\pi P^{2}} d\theta$ ?

Comment: We started out with $$f(Q,\theta|P)dQ\,d\theta=\frac1{\pi P^2}Q\,dQ\,d\theta$$ and we had to integrate over all $\theta$ to get eliminate the dependence on $\theta$ to $f(Q|P)dQ$ as a function of $Q$ alone.

Answer (score -1):

Being the distribution of P uniform on the unit circle, the expected value of the radius of $P$ is $1/2$.
Therefore, the expected value of the radius of Q, uniformly distributed between $0$ and $|P|$ is $1/2\times1/2=1/4$

Comment: Is there a way to solve it more explicitly, setting up integrals, using conditional distributions? I really want to get a grasp of that concept, as the chapter is about conditional distributions..